# How can I connect to a BlackFish Database in another PC

Tags: delphi, database-connection, blackfish

I am trying to connect to a BlackFish database in another machine using win32 dbExpress 4 database driver.

Server is start in both machines, local and remote.

Database is up in both machines local and remote.

--- UPDATE ---

this is my configuration:
[image]

"devmobilWRK" is the remote machine.

This is the result of the test Connection:
[image]

Both machine have the same port - 2508

I have delphi 2007 installed in both machines

Comment: @Jlouro you open the port 2508 in the firewall of the server machine?

Comment: @Jlouro: BlackfishSQL is a discontinued product (just to make sure you know) http://reviews.cnet.com/search-results/blackfish-sql-server-deployment/1707-5_7-33215820.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jlouro, you must read the Embarcadero documentation about connect to a remote or local Blackfish server.

- [Blackfish SQL Overview](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Blackfish_SQL_Overview)
- [Blackfish SQL Developer's Guide: Contents](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Blackfish_SQL_Help_Contents)
- [`Blackfish SQL : Establishing Connections`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Establishing_Connections)

Comment: @Jlouro, You're missing to tell us, if you already read that, what's wrong after the connection is configured the way documentation says, do you get an error message? application crashes? or how do you know you're not connected?